# [rollup][typescript]Build failed because `import type {} from '*.ts'`

Tags: typescript, rollup

i wrote this line at my entry file index.ts
`import type { num } from 'types/index'`
then run script **rollup --config**

result to this error:

```bash
src/index.ts → dist/index.js...
[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/index.ts (1:12)
1: import type { num } from "../types/index";
               ^
```

heres my files:

```js
// src/index.ts
import { num } from "../types/index";
import flex from "./log";

export default function add(x: num, y: num) {
  flex();
  return x + y;
}

// src/log.ts
export default function flex() {
  console.log("This is too simple");
}

// types/index.ts
export type num = number;
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  /* Read more via https://aka.ms/tsconfig */
  "extends": "@tsconfig/recommended/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    /** same directory as rollup output */
    "outDir": "dist",
    /** generate declarations right next to the output */
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src": ["src"],
      "types": ["types"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

rollup.config.js

```js
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: {
    file: "dist/index.js",
    format: "es",
  },
  plugins: [typescript()],
};
```

package.json

```json
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.2",
    "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/babel__core": "^7.20.1",
    "rollup": "^3.25.3",
    "tslib": "^2.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

env

platform: WSL2(unbuntu)

NodeJS：18.16.0

i've tried replace `import type { num } from 'types/index'` to `import { type } from 'types/index'`

it goes like

```bash
src/index.ts → dist/index.js...
[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/index.ts (4:29)
2: import flex from "./log";
3: 
4: export default function add(x: num, y: num) {
                                ^
```

when i delete this line and type directly `type num = number`, it works...

Expecte **rollup --config** works with original code